# wkwebview can not capture screen for webgl page

Tags: webgl, screenshot, wkwebview

I find that wkwebview can  not capture screen for webgl page. I have try many method provided by others in stackoverflow, but they do not work when i open a page rendered by WebGL. Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I found that Chrome and Safari which use WKWebView have such issue too.

Comment: @user5612625 Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: You could create an image from the  shader target (multipass).